# How to pull out substrings (words) from string?

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I'm trying to input a four word sentence, and then be able to print out each word individually using indexOf and substrings. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edited

So is this what it should look like? I've ran it twice and received two different answers, so I'm not sure if my program running the program is faulty or my program itself is faulty.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arithmetic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String sentence;
    String word1, word2, word3, word4;
    int w1, w2, w3, w4;
    int p, p2, p3, p4;

    System.out.print("Enter a sentence with 4 words: ");
    sentence = in.nextLine();

    p = sentence.indexOf(" ");



    word1 = sentence.substring(0,p)+" ";
    w1 = 1 + word1.length();
    p2 = word1.indexOf(" ");
    word2 = sentence.substring(w1,p2);
    w2 = w1+1+word2.length();
    p3 = word2.indexOf(" ");
    word3 = sentence.substring(w2,p3);
    w3 = w1+w2+1+word3.length();
    p4 = word3.indexOf(" ");
    word4 = sentence.substring(w3,p4);
    w4 = w1+w2+w3+1+word4.length();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two things:

1. You're not computing the indices correctly. The starting index for the third word should be something like `length of first word + 1 + length of second word + 1`, but it looks like you're leaving out the length of the first word. Similarly, when you're getting the fourth word, you're leaving out the lengths of the first two words.
2. `indexOf(" ")` will only get you the index of the first occurrence of a space. After you get the first space, you're reusing that index instead of using the indices of the other spaces.

Lastly, after you fix those two, if you know that the words are going to be delimited by spaces, then you might want to look at the [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function. Using that, you could split your sentence without having to do all of the space-finding yourself.

Comment: So how do I have the indices of space's after the first occurrence?

Comment: @CooperTaylor Looking at the docs, I see another 
[`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) taking two arguments, the second of which specifying which index to start from. That function should help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I hardly suggest not to use `substring` and `indexOf`, both for performance reasons, readability, and bugs. Consider any of the following (all of these are considering words as non-whitespace characters):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int wordNo = 0;

    System.out.println("using a Scanner (exactly 4 words):");

    InputStream in0 = new ByteArrayInputStream("a four word sentence".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(/*System.*/in0);

    try {
        String word1 = scanner.next();
        String word2 = scanner.next();
        String word3 = scanner.next();
        String word4 = scanner.next();
        System.out.printf("1: %s, 2: %s, 3: %s, 4: %s\n", word1, word2, word3, word4);
    } catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        System.err.println("The sentence is shorter than 4 words");
    }

    System.out.println("\nusing a Scanner (general):");

    InputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("this is a sentence".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    for(Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(/*System.*/in1); scanner1.hasNext(); ) {
        String word = scanner1.next();
        System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", ++wordNo, word);
    }


    System.out.println("\nUsing BufferedReader and split:");

    InputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream("this is another sentence".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(/*System.*/in2));
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for(String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", ++wordNo, word);
        }
    }
}
```